Is it possible to solve for $p(x)$ given $\int f(x, y) p(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $y$?
Given $0\le x\le 1$, $p(x)\ge0$ and $\int_0^1 p(x)\,dx=1$, is it possible to solve $p(x)$, given
$$\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,p(x)\,dx=0,\ {\rm for\ all}\ y\ {\rm satisfying}\ 0\le y\le 1$$
where $f(x,y)$ is defined to be
$$f(x,y)={\rm sin}(2\pi(x-y))$$
I know there are trivial solutions such as $p(x)=1$, $p(x)=\frac{δ(x)}{2}+\frac{δ(x-1/2)}{2}$, and etc. But I wonder if there is a way to methodically get to these solutions, and if the method applies to a generic $f(x,y)$.
Thank you very much for your time and help!

Are you familiar with convolution?

Oh! I don't know how I did not realize that this is just convolution. Then, is there a way to identify the set of probability distribution function p(x) that is orthogonal f(x)?
